# Should the 'Ask us anything' link point here now?

Tags: discussion

elementary's blog has an [Ask us anything](http://blog.elementary.io/ask) link that apparently point to Tumblr?

Should that be re-directed here or is that a completely different thing?

Comment: You'd need to contact elementary I guess - and also remember people will be put off from a beta site

Comment: Yeah, that's why I ask here where Daniel and others will now be active. I'm not sure people will be put off by a beta. In any case, I'm not sure this site will go out of beta any time soon, so it's best to get accustomed to the fact. The requirements to lift the 'beta' tag are quite strict, some sites have had them for *years*.

Comment: Yes, and they are considering atually removing "beta" even if they don't graduate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aren't we in a *private* beta right now? I think as soon as we go public beta it would be worth linking to StackExchange. But the "Ask us anything" in the blog is more about asking developers non-support questions like "What do you think about Atom?" or even "Puppies or Kittens?". It's stuff I don't think would be appropriate here.

Comment: Indeed, we are in *private* beta right now. Thanks for the clarification on the 'Ask us anything' link.